# Flutter Gesture Detector transform.scale animate but doesn't uncolor the unselected items

Tags: flutter, colors, transform, selecteditem, gesturedetector

in my flutter project, I'm creating my own chips. There are 4 of them. I'm using a decorated container and a Gesture detector to catch any tap.
I wanna achieve this behavior: when the user taps a chip there is an animation that makes it act like a button (I'm using a `transform.scale` in order to get that) and becomes selected. The last chip selected changes to unselected mode. I wanna have only 1 chip selected out of 4.

`

```
class ChipTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final index;

  const ChipTile({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.index,
  });

  @override
  State<ChipTile> createState() => _ChipTileState();
}

class _ChipTileState extends State<ChipTile>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  //animation on tap
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  void onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    _animationController.reverse();
  }

  void onTapCancel() {
    _animationController.reverse();
  }

  //----------------------------
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scale = 1 + _animationController.value; 

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          globals.selectedChip = widget.index;
        });
      },
      onTapDown: onTapDown,
      onTapUp: onTapUp,
      onTapCancel: onTapCancel,
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: scale,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          width: 70,
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                widget.text, 
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: globals.selectedChip == widget.index
                  ? Colors.blue[100]
                  : Colors.grey[300],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

The animation is going well, but the coloring of the chips has bad behavior.
The last selected chips don't become unselected when I select a different chip.
[chips that are all selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGj2v.png)

Comment: ` globals.selectedChip` is an int to store selected item?

Comment: yeah, i have created my_globals.dart file that contains selectedChip int to store selected item

Answer (score 0):

All the buttons `ChipTile` have their own state, and clicking on one single button doesn't trigger others state.  You need to connect all button tap event somehow. I am using `ValueNotifier` and keeping the widget minimal to get the concept.

```dart
ValueNotifier<int?> selectedChip = ValueNotifier(null);

class ChipTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final int index;

  const ChipTile({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.index,
  });

  @override
  State<ChipTile> createState() => _ChipTileState();
}

class _ChipTileState extends State<ChipTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        selectedChip.value = widget.index;
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: selectedChip,
        builder: (context, value, child) => Container(
          child: Text(
            widget.text,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            color: value == widget.index.toInt()
                ? Colors.blue[100]
                : Colors.grey[300],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Test on a scaffold body

```dart
body: Column(
    children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        ChipTile(
          index: i,
          text: "i $i",
        ),
    ],
  ),
```